# Website not secured after making backend call. SSL problem

Tags: java, html, spring, ssl

I bought SSL for my domain, implemented it and everything was fine. Website seemed secured. Afterwards, I used the same SSL to create newCert.p12 file using spring boot and created the file.
I've put it in resources and everything seemed okay as well.

```
server.ssl.key-store-type=pkcs12
server.ssl.key-password=changeit
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:newCert.p12
```

I put one html file to make API call

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
Test

<script>
    const url= `https://194.182.xx.x:8081/api/search/vehicle/number`;

    fetch(url)
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log("other")
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('There was a problem with the fetch operation:', error);
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

xx - used to hide real address

All tho everything works and data is fetched properly (it is just number) website stopped being secured. I got this error:

This site has a valid certificate from a trusted certificate authority.

However, some parts of the website are not secure. This means that information such as passwords or credit card details will not be sent securely to this website and may be intercepted or viewed by others.

I expected website to be secured. I deleted every html file, elaving just clean one file but it doesn't help. I am  not really knowledgeable about that SSL things so I hope I get some help here.

Comment: This is not really a programming question. My guess would be that you send, receive, and store passwords directly in full name instead of using hashes.

Comment: nah, i use hashes everywhere but i tried to connect it to just one app with 1 controller and result is the same

Comment: What do you mean by buy SSL?

Comment: Kinda hard to answer this with the information here, but chances are that something on your page is being loaded over HTTP.  If you're using HTTPS, then all resources also need to be retrieved over HTTPS, or you'll end up with mixed content, and most browsers will consider this insecure because it opens you up to man-in-the-middle attacks.

Comment: @lane.maxwell how tho? my front-end is only one file test, the one pasted here

Comment: @kawaxanax this is impossible to answer, there are many reasons why this could be happening.  Right click in your browser and inspect the network traffic, see what it's doing.